# how to get data from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

This is the JSON i get access to:

```
[{"Nombre":"Craic Irish Pub","Descripcion":"Pub estilo     Irlandes","Telefono":"234234","SitioWeb":"","Horario":"Viernes - Sabados 17:00-    24:00","Parqueo":"No","Ubicacion":"San Jose","Reservas":"Si","_id":"5449b3334d50a38754000003","__v":0},   {"Nombre":"TicoPub","Descripcion":"Pub    Moderno","Telefono":"34534534","SitioWeb":"ticopub.com","Horario":"Viernes - Sabados 17:00-    24:00","Parqueo":"Si","Ubicacion":"Lindora","Reservas":"Si","_id":"5449b3cd4d50a38754000006","__v":0}]
```

i can read it and save it as a JSONObject (named json) however i can't do this:
   JSONArray values = json.getJSONArray(0)
how can i access it?

Comment: which api are you using for this

Comment: Sigh!!  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then figure out why what you have is not a JSON object but rather a JSON array, and what it has inside is not a JSON array but rather a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely cannot store that JSON in a `JSONObject`, since it is **NOT** a JSON object. It is a JSON array. So use a `JSONArray` to store it.

Comment: i cannot or i should not? because i can store it as a JSON objct

Comment: @DiegöRivera If your JSON string is of the form `[...]`, then you definitely cannot create a `JSONObject` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you typed I assumed you're using json.org's library. As Sotirios pointed out, whenever you have '[]' in a json string that means you're using array. You must first create a Json array and then you can access the individual object (you have two of them). See below:

```
String jsonString = "[{'Nombre':'Craic Irish Pub','Descripcion':'Pub estilo  " +
        "   Irlandes','Telefono':'234234','SitioWeb':'','Horario':'Viernes - Sabados 17:00-    24:00'," +
        "'Parqueo':'No','Ubicacion':'San Jose','Reservas':'Si','_id':'5449b3334d50a38754000003','__v':0},  " +
        " {'Nombre':'TicoPub','Descripcion':'Pub    Moderno','Telefono':'34534534','SitioWeb':'ticopub.com','Horario':'Viernes - Sabados 17:00-    24:00'," +
        "'Parqueo':'Si','Ubicacion':'Lindora','Reservas':'Si','_id':'5449b3cd4d50a38754000006','__v':0}]";

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
String nombre = obj.getString("Nombre");
System.out.println(nombre); //prints 'Craic Irish Pub'
```